# How can i get a column from 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
char[][] isbns = {
                {'9', '6', '0', '-', '4', '2', '5', '-', '0', '5', '9', '-', '0'},
                {'8', '0', '-', '9', '0', '2', '7', '4', '4', '-', '1', '-', '6'},
                {'0', '-', '8', '0', '4', '4', '-', '2', '9', '5', '8', '-', 'X'},
                {'0', '-', '9', '4', '3', '3', '9', '6', '-', '0', '4', '-', '2'},
                {'0', '-', '9', '7', '5', '2', '2', '9', '8', '-', '0', '-', '5'},
                {'9', '9', '7', '1', '-', '5', '-', '0', '2', 'l', '0', '-', '0'},
                {'9', '3', '-', '8', '6', '5', '4', '-', '-', '2', '1', '-', '4'},
                {'9', '9', '9', '2', '1', '-', '5', '8', '8', '-', '1', '0', '7'}
        };
```

array is as like this on top and my method is as follows

```
public static Object[] getColumn(char[][] arr, int index){
        Object[] column = new Object[arr[0].length];
        for(int i = 0; i < column.length; i++){
            column[i] = arr[i][index];
        }
        return column;
    }
```

However as rows are 8 and columns are 13 characters, i get array index out of bounds exception error.

How can i solve this issue ? thanks.

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A column has the same length as the number of rows, which is the number of elements in `arr`.

So change

```
Object[] column = new Object[arr[0].length];
```

to

```
Object[] column = new Object[arr.length];
```